# What are the solutions of the equation $3np+3n+2=n^2+p^2$, with n and p positive integers?

Tags: number-theory, vieta-jumping

Trying to find the solutions of $3np+3n+2=n^2+p^2$ with n and p positive integers, I found out n=14 and p=4 is a solution, but I want to know if there are others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a slight variant of Vieta Jumping. For a given solution $(n,p)$ we can travel around the given hyperbola  by
$$  (n,p) \mapsto (3p+3 - n, p) $$
and 
$$ (n,p) \mapsto (n, 3n-p) $$
To keep going, alternate the maps. If you double any mapping you go back where you started

It is also possible to separate the variables. The sequence of $n$ values obeys
$$ n_{j+2}= 7 n_{j+1} - n_j + 6 \; , $$ while the sequence of $p$ values obeys the similar
$$ p_{j+2}= 7 p_{j+1} - p_j + 9 \; . $$
Each $n$ or $p$ value occurs in two consecutive solutions, owing to the zigzag way the solutions move out on the two branches of the hyperbola in the first quadrant.

[image]
probably better to make vertical
$$ (1,4) $$
$$ (14 , 4 )$$ 
$$ (14 , 38 )$$ 
$$ (103 , 38 )$$ 
$$ (103 , 271 )$$ 
$$ (713 , 271 )$$ 
$$ (713 , 1868 )$$ 
$$ (4894 , 1868 )$$ 
$$ (4894 , 12814 )$$ 
$$ (33551 , 12814 )$$ 
$$ (33551 , 87839 )$$ 
$$ (229969 , 87839 )$$ 
$$ (229969 , 602068 )$$ 
$$ (1576238 , 602068 )$$ 
$$ (1576238 , 4126646 )$$ 
$$ (10803703 , 4126646 )$$ 
$$ (10803703 , 28284463 )$$ 
$$ (74049689 , 28284463 )$$ 
$$ (74049689 , 193864604 )$$ 
$$ (507544126 , 193864604 )$$ 
$$ (507544126 , 1328767774 )$$ 
$$ (3478759199 , 1328767774 )$$ 
$$ (3478759199 , 9107509823 )$$ 
$$ (23843770273 , 9107509823 )$$ 
$$ (23843770273 , 62423800996 )$$ 
$$ (163427632718 , 62423800996 )$$ 
$$ (163427632718 , 427859097158 )$$ 
$$ (1120149658759 , 427859097158 )$$ 
$$ (1120149658759 , 2932589879119 )$$ 
$$ (7677619978601 , 2932589879119 )$$ 
$$ (7677619978601 , 20100270056684 )$$ 
$$ (52623190191454 , 20100270056684 )$$ 
$$ (52623190191454 , 137769300517678 )$$ 
$$ (360684711361583 , 137769300517678 )$$ 
$$ (360684711361583 , 944284833567071 )$$ 
$$ (2472169789339633 , 944284833567071 )$$ 
$$ (2472169789339633 , 6472224534451828 )$$ 
$$ (16944503814015854 , 6472224534451828 )$$ 
$$ (16944503814015854 , 44361286907595734 )$$ 
$$ (116139356908771351 , 44361286907595734 )$$ 
$$ (116139356908771351 , 304056783818718319 )$$ 
$$ (796030994547383609 , 304056783818718319 )$$ 
$$ (796030994547383609 , 2084036199823432508 )$$ 
$$ (5456077604922913918 , 2084036199823432508 )$$ 
$$ (5456077604922913918 , 14284196614945309246 )$$ 
$$ (37396512239913013823 , 14284196614945309246 )$$ 
$$ (37396512239913013823 , 97905340104793732223 )$$ 
$$ (256319508074468182849 , 97905340104793732223 )$$ 
$$ (256319508074468182849 , 671053184118610816324 )$$ 
$$ (1756840044281364266126 , 671053184118610816324 )$$ 
$$ (1756840044281364266126 , 4599466948725481982054 )$$

```
  mpz_class n = 1;
mpz_class p = 4;
  for(int k = 1; k <= 25; ++k)
 {

   n = 3 * p + 3 - n;
   cout << "$$ (" << n << " , " << p << " )$$ " << endl;
    p = 3 * n - p;
      cout << "$$ (" << n << " , " << p << " )$$ " << endl;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are base solutions $n=-1,p=-2$ and $n=-2,p=-2$  Starting with either one, you can use either of two recurrences

$$n' = 3 ⁢n - 8 p - 12 \\
p' = 8 ⁢n - 21 ⁢p - 30$$

and also:

$$n' = - 21 n + 8 p - 12 \\
p' = - 8 n + 3 p - 6$$

This gives the following four sets of solutions

[image]

Answers found with the help of the [Alpertron](https://www.alpertron.com.ar/QUAD.HTM), but it missed the $-2,-2$ base solution.

Comment: I don't think you have (103, 271) or (713, 271) or (33551, 87839) or ( 229969, 87839)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an *answer* but a **request** for a **manual derivation** of all positive integer solutions.  Below is my *work* which hit a brick wall. If helpful, anyone is welcome to piggyback off of my work.

Re-organizing terms, $\;n^2 + n(-3p - 3) + (p^2 - 2) = 0 \;\Rightarrow\;$ 
$n = \frac{1}{2}\left[3p+3 \pm \sqrt{5p^2 + 18p + 17}\;\right].$

Therefore, there exists $k$ such that $3p+3+k$ is an even positive integer and
$\;5p^2 + 18p + (17-k^2) = 0 \;\Rightarrow\;$ 
$p = \frac{1}{10}\left[\;-18 \pm \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{5k^2 - 4}\;\right]. $

My knowledge of **Pell Equations** is limited to $x^2 - Dy^2 = \pm 1.$
My understanding (which could be in error) is that there has been work done on (for example) $L^2 - 5k^2 = -4.$

Comment: suggest going through the questions with https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vieta-jumping